# What is a term for an item that can both be inserted and removed?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a term to describe an item that be be inserted (Addition) into or removed (Deletion) from a list of other items.  The closest I can think of is "swappable," but that implies I am interchanging the items, which is not the case.

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide an example of how you wish to use this.

Comment: Don't you think that's automatically assumed by "can be" instead of "must be" or "is" inserted/removed?

Comment: How about "optional"?

Comment: I think you have to focus on what the "thing" is, and then explain what can be done with it. So "items" or "cookies" or "robots" or whatever can be inserted and deleted from "lists" or "collections" or this other thing. I don't know if there's a way to name something that both 1) describes the thing well, and, 2) describes its insertability/deletability. If you know what I mean.

Comment: Check the definition of "fungible"

Comment: 'options' can be either included or removed although some options are 'swappable' and others are not.   A "Sunroof" might be an option, as would "snow-tires" but you couldn't have both a "sunroof" and a "moonroof" or "snow tires" and "racing tires"

Comment: Try "*commutable*"

Comment: A plug or a plug-in can be inserted and removed from a socket. It’s used a lot in software and computing.

Comment: Yep, "pluggable".

Comment: This is a "build your own car" problem--or "build your own computer"? Depending on where you start, you can add or remove a "deluxe" option.

Comment: @JeffUK, an example of this would be an adjective to describe an item that could be placed and/or picked up.  i.e. placing a stapler on a desk, then later removing it.

Comment: Thank you everyone for all these suggestions!  We are going to have a lot of fun discussing the language of each!

Comment: I’m a computer geek, so I’ll suggest “module” or “modular”.  (Has also been applied to low-tech things like furniture and Lego.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways of answering this question.

First, at the programming level, the *item* is typically an object, and the *list* is an object that can contain other objects. The ability to add and remove objects is usually a property of the container. There is no special adjective for the object.

At the higher semantic level it’s different. The item is *represented* by the object, but it also corresponds to something in the external world. It can have significant properties of its own. For example, the item can be addable to a list, or removable from a list, and the list itself contains items that are subject to some further action, e.g. bought, cooked, painted on a boat, etc. However, at this point you need an adjective that works with in the external world with both the item and the collection, and without more information it’s hard to give a good answer.

That said, here are some general adjectives that apply to items that can be added and removed from collections:

- listable,
- collectible,
- placeable,
- eligible,
- available.